# MongoDB - how to update values by string operations

Tags: mongodb

I have field `id` in database with values in pattern `entity_id_aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd`. I need to change pattern with underlines and replace all `-` 's to `_` to underlines in all existing documents ( the final result should be `entity_id_aaaa_bbbb_cccc_dddd`), is there any update query in MongoDb that will help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({id:id}).forEach(function(document) {
    document.id = document.id.replace('entity_id_aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd', 'entity_id_aaaa_bbbb_cccc_dddd');
    db.collection.save(document);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just changed several things and it worked great  `var k = document.id.replace(/-/g, '_');
    db.node_person.update(
    {"id": document.id},
    {"$set" : {"id" : k} }
    );`
In this way all `-` characters are replaced and updated .